# could not find member convert from string interpolation segment

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I have a users class in my firebase JSON file .. it has the following child nodes:

- Age
- Location
- About
- Image

From my app I am trying to enter the age of the logged in user and update it in the JSON file.

I wrote the code :

```
ref.childByAppendingPath("users\(ref.authData.uid)/Age")
   .updateChildValues(AgeTextField.text)
```

But it gives error:

> could not find member convert from string interpolation segment

Please help me what line of code should I write to update the age and other info of logged in user?

Comment: Can you show log of compete users object?

Comment: @Shoaib, there isn't a users object it's part of the string. `ref.authData.uid` should be a string as well.

Comment: Is this runtime or compile time?

Comment: this is a compile time error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interpolation looks correct. However, you're most likely not authenticated. The `authData` property only exists when a user have been authenticated to the Firebase database.

There is another problem in the `updateChildValues` function.

`updateChildValues` expects a dictionary of `[String: AnyObject]`. This is a non destructive update. It will only update values provided in the dictionary.

Try this instead.

```
ref.childByAppendingPath("users\(ref.authData.uid)")
  .updateChildValues(["age": AgeTextField.text])
```

But if you really want to drill down into the `Age` node you can just use `setValue` for a String update.

```
ref.childByAppendingPath("users\(ref.authData.uid)/Age")
  .setValue(AgeTextField.text)
```

`setValue` is a destructive update. This means it will replace everything at that node's location. However, since you're only accessing a single property of a node it doesn't matter that the update is destructive.

Comment: David one more thing.. now i am trying to display this child nodes info in a label on a view controller. what should i code ? how can i get the snapshot of the child nodes kindly help i am new to swift and fire base

Comment: how do i display the stored info in child nodes in a label on a view controller? please help

Comment: I'll answer this in the question you asked separately. Please resolve this one if it worked for you :)

Comment: yes please do answer me on that question thank you :) @David East